# VB.NET Date invalid cast

Tags: vb.net, datetime, casting

What is wrong with my code please?

```
    Dim iYearOld As Integer = 2010
    Dim iYearNow As Integer = 2014

    Dim iAge As Integer
    iAge = DateDiff("y", iYearOld, iYearNow)
```

The error

> "Invalid cast: Argument 'Date1' can not be cast to type Date"

Can somebody help? Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `iYearNow - iYearOld`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter LOL, yes, you are right, thank you. Anyway... what was the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clearly telling you what is wrong.

`DateDiff` requires 2 date parameters whereas you are passing it 2 integers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

> > What is wrong with my code please?

You are sending in integers to a function that requires dates:

[DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

second permeter and third is date not integer

```
Dim datTim1 As Date = #1/4/2001#
Dim datTim2 As Date = #1/9/2001#
' Assume Sunday is specified as first day of the week. 
Dim wD As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday, datTim1, datTim2)
Dim wY As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, datTim1, datTim2)
```